# How to use user input date as a positional argument for a class?

Tags: python

```
import datetime

class JoiningDetails:

    Name = str(input("Enter the name : "))

    def __init__(self,x):

        self.x = x
        
    def output(self):
        print (Name.x)
        

    def getDoJ(self):

        Name.x = input("Enter the date of Joining of the employee in YYYY/MM/DD format\t:\t")
        
Name = JoiningDetails()
Name.getDoJ()
Name.output()
```

The user has to provide date as input and use the same as the positional argument for the class, **instead of** manually providing the argument in:
Name =  JoiningDetails(DD/MM/YYY)

Any date format is fine.

```
Name = JoiningDetails()
Name.getDoJ()
Name.output()
```

No argument would be provided manually within the object definition but it should take it from the user input.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a function inside the class and then you can pass it as a positional argument while creating the object.

I'll give you a simple example to understand, you could possibly can refactor it according to your needs.

```
from datetime import datetime


class JoiningDetails:
    def __init__(self, joining_date):
        self.joining_date = joining_date

    def on_input(self):
        # Get name and date from user
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        date = input("Enter date in DD/MM/YYYY format: ")

        # Convert date to datetime object
        date = datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")

        #  YYYY/MM/DD format\t:\t
        return f"{name} joined on {date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')}"

    def get_joining_date(self):

        return self.joining_date


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create object of JoiningDetails class and pass on_input method as argument
    obj = JoiningDetails(JoiningDetails.on_input(JoiningDetails))

    # Print the joining date
    print(obj.get_joining_date())
```